# Hashmap values are not getting proprely using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript . I created one hashmap in javascript

```
var usermap=new Map()
```

and then set the key value are

```
for(var i=0;i<data.lenght;i++) {
    usermap.set(data.Id[i],[data.value[i],data.status[]i]  
}
```

i set one key and multiple values now i want to get data.value of particular key.  please help me out!

Comment: Is this `status[]i` a typo during posting or you have it in your code?

Comment: and `data.lenght`...

Answer (score 0):

There are some typo in the code and some more errors, assuming this was what you wanted to achieve. The following errors were evident:

1. In the for loop `data.length` signifies it is an array
2. If data is an array, you cannot access it with data.Id,data.value or
   data.status. Objects are accessed in this way.
3. If data is an object, then data.length would be undefined and it wouldn't loop.

```js
var usermap=new Map();

var data = [{'Id':1,'value':'val1','status':true},{'Id':2,'value':'val1','status':true},{'Id':3,'value':'val1','status':true}]

for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
              {
                 usermap.set(data[i].Id,[data[i].value,data[i].status]);  
              }

console.log(usermap.get(2)[0])
```

Comment: First, its bad to answer a typo mistake. Second, if there are other mistakes as well, please point it out in your answer. Just working code is not enough

Comment: Ok sure... I'll edit it.. sorry for the wrong convention